# Protected structs in static classes

Tags: c#, struct, static, protected

In C#, this :

```
static class foo
{
    protected void doThing(); // CS1057
    {

    }
}
```

Generates the CS1057 compiler error, as static classes don't support inheritance.

So why is this allowed? What is the meaning of the `protected` keyword in this context?

```
static class foo
{
    protected struct bar
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - I get a compiler error in .NET 4.7.2 but not .NET 5  or Roslyn. I wonder if it's a compiler bug or a new feature?

Comment: i have my langage version set in "preview" in csproj. There might me a bug with the langage as i'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 too

Comment: Maybe somebody can explain why I should care about it? There are a lot much more interesting and important staff in c# and VS.

Comment: due to the fact that VS2019 throws a lot of errors when I try to work with this code, I would say that most likely this is a bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is definitely a bug, and I would suggest you file it.**

---

[ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf), the official specification for C#, says the following

> **15.2.2.4 Static classes
>
> 15.2.2.4.1 General**
>
> *...snip...*
> A static class declaration is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - *...snip...*
> - A static class shall not have members with `protected` or `protected internal` declared accessibility.

Don't tell me that this excludes nested types, because a few lines later, nested types are specifically excluded from the `static` modifier restrictions:

> The members of a static class are not automatically static, and the member declarations shall explicitly include a `static` modifier (except for constants and nested types).